# docker.sock: permission denied when using testContainers with Podman on Windows

Tags: permissions, containers, testcontainers, podman

My Java & Spring Boot application integration tests use `testContainers` and I'm using [Podman](https://podman.io/) on my Windows machine.

When trying to run the integration tests, I'm getting this permission error:

```
Failed to load ApplicationContext
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
 .....
Caused by: com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.InternalServerErrorException: Status 500: {"cause":"permission denied","message":"container create: statfs /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied","response":500}
```

And all the integration tests fail.

Is there a specific permission command I need to provide Podman?

Answer (score -2):

I was able to overcome the issue only after switching from Podman to [Rancher Desktop](https://rancherdesktop.io/).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The user is trying to run Podman not Rancher.